# Print a different long description in nose tests along with test name python

Tags: python, nose, python-unittest

I am using the command:

```
nosetests test.py
```

When this is run only the first line of the description gets printed.
I want the whole description along with the test name. How do i do that?

test.py file

```
import unittests

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_1(self):
       """this is a long description //
              continues on second line which does not get printed """
       some code;
       self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_2(self):
       """this is another or different long description //
              continues on second line which does not get printed """
       some code;
       self.assertTrue(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Unittest is [documented as only showing the first line](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.shortDescription) of the test method's docstring.  But you could override the default implementation of `shortDescription` method to customise that behaviour:

```
import unittest

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def shortDescription(self):
        return self._testMethodDoc

    def test_1(self):
       """this is a long description //
              continues on second line """
       self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_2(self):
       """this is another or different long description //
              continues on second line which also gets printed :) """
       self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Demo:

```
$ nosetests -v example.py 
this is a long description //
              continues on second line ... ok
this is another or different long description //
              continues on second line which also gets printed :) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Someone wrote a nose plugin to fix this exact annoyance, maybe you'd be interested to use that.  Here it is:  https://bitbucket.org/natw/nose-description-fixer-plugin/

Comment: I think I've seen the hack before somewhere on SO, but +1 anyway.